# PHP date-date = remaining days till the end of the year

Tags: php, datetime

Soo as for the excercise I'm supposed to make a function that counts remaining days untill the end of year for example:

```
$currentDate = date('d-m-Y');
$endOfYear = date('31-12-2023');
```

and lets say `$currenDate - $endOfYear = .....days`

This is what i made

```
$date1 = date('d-m-Y');
$date2 = "2023-12-31";

$diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
```

and the answer is = `2937600`
how do I convert this into days?

Comment: You could use the 'z' date format that gives you the day number of the year, then subtract one number from the other https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php.  Or alternatively use `date_diff` https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: $diffInDays = floor(2937600 / 86400); // 34 (days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are getting from `$diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);` is in seconds ([php strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)). So to convert this to days you can simply use a mathematical transformation:

```
$diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
$days = $diff / 86400;
```

If you need an integer number (a number not containing decimals) you can use `floor()` function to round down, and `ceil()` function to round up:

```
$days = floor($diff / 86400); // rounds down
$days = ceil($diff / 86400); // rounds up
```

More information on [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) and [ceil()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).